# For A, find an f:A -> N choice function that is also an $f:(A,\subseteq)$ -> (N,<=) ordinal isomorphic function, explain

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question:

For $\mathscr{A}$, find an  $f:\mathscr{A}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ choice function that is also an $f:(\mathscr{A},\subseteq)\rightarrow(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ ordinal isomorphic function. Explain.

---

Hi, I have solved the question and want to be sure that it is correct.

---

My solution:

$\mathscr{A}$ is a non-empty set and let its non-empty subsets' non-empty family to be $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$

$\mathscr{A}=\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},...\{1,2,3,...,i\}\space\vert\space i\in I\text{ and }I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$

$A_1=\{1\},A_2=\{1,2\},...A_i=\{1,2,...,i\}\space\space(i\in I$ and $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}\}\space\space\mathscr{A}=\{A_1,A_2,...,A_i\space\vert\space i\in I\text{ and }I\subseteq\mathbb{N}\}$

Then
$\mathscr{A}=\cup^\infty_{i=1}A_i$ and $I\subseteq I$

Let function f to be like this:

$f(1)=1\in A_1=\{1\}, 1\in\mathbb{N}$

$f(2)=2\in A_2=\{1,2\}, 2\in\mathbb{N}$

$f(3)=3\in A_3=\{1,2,3\}, 3\in\mathbb{N}$

So, because $f\in\Pi_{i\in I}A_i=\{f\space\vert\space f:I\rightarrow\cup_{i\in I}A_i\text{ function and for }\forall i\in I$ is $f(i)=i\in A_i\}$, function f is a choice function.

Function $f$ is a bijection and $f:\mathscr{A}\to \mathbb{N}$ is a increasing function.

$$\mathscr{A}\space\space\space\underrightarrow{f}\space\space\space\mathbb{N}$$

$$\overset{A_i=\{1,2,3,...,i\}}{}\longrightarrow\overset{f(i)=i\in I, I\subseteq\mathbb{N}}{}$$
$$\overset{A_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}}{\uparrow}\longrightarrow\overset{5}{\uparrow}$$
$$\overset{A_4=\{1,2,3,4\}}{\uparrow}\longrightarrow\overset{4}{\uparrow}$$
$$\overset{A_3=\{1,2,3\}}{\uparrow}\longrightarrow\overset{3}{\uparrow}$$
$$\overset{A_2=\{1,2\}}{\uparrow}\longrightarrow\overset{2}{\uparrow}$$
$$\overset{A_1=\{1\}}{}\longrightarrow\overset{1}{}$$

$f:\mathscr{A}\to \mathbb{N}$ is a ordinal isomorphic transformation.

$A_{i-1}\leq A_i\iff f(A_{i-1}\leq f(A_i)$

Comment: You have not told us what $\mathscr{A}$ is, or what properties it is assumed to have.

Comment: Question does not give any information about it but I take it as a "non-empty set" as I described it in my solution.

$\mathscr{A}\not=\emptyset$

Comment: $\mathscr{A}$ must be some collection of sets in order for the notation $(\mathscr{A},\subseteq)$ to make sense. It must also be countable in order for there to be such a function $f$. I'm afraid your solution is rather incomprehensible. At one point you suggest that $\mathscr{A}$ is the set of sets $\{A_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $A_i=\{1,2,\ldots,i\}$. At another point you say that $\mathscr{A}$ is the *union* of the $A_i$'s, but this union would just be $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Then you define a function $f$ such that $f(i)=i$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. So the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$, not $\mathscr{A}$ (presumably). And finally you claim $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. But neither $A$ nor $B$ are defined.

Comment: It appears that what you are trying to show is that if $\mathscr{A}$ is the collection of sets $\{1,\ldots,i\}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, then the mapping that sends $\{1,\ldots,i\}$ to $i$ is a choice function and an order isomorphism (with the subset ordering on $\mathscr{A}$). But your proof is hard to read (for the reasons stated above), and it's not clear from the statement of the problem that this is actually what $\mathscr{A}$ is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. What do you suggest me to do in order to fix my solution?

Comment: Yes, $\mathsrc{A}$ is set of sets.

I didn't understand what is wrong.

Comment: f A to B should be $\mathscr{A}\to\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your argument you need to:

1. Verify that $\mathscr{A}$ is supposed to be the following set of sets
   $$
   \{A_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}
   $$
   where $A_i=\{1,\ldots,i\}$. This is not clearly stated in the problem and so the solution doesn't make sense without first fixing the statement of the problem. A proof of a theorem is useless if the theorem isn't stated accurately.
2. Assuming $\mathscr{A}$ is actually the set in the first step, then the first few lines of your proof just need to be rewritten more clearly. For example, the phrase "let its non-empty subsets' non-empty family" is very confusing. It almost sounds like you are saying to enumerate the *subsets* of $\mathscr{A}$, but from the notation it appears you are just listing the *elements* of $\mathscr{A}$ (which are themselves sets yes, but are not subsets of $\mathscr{A}$). Also the next few lines in which you rewrite $\mathscr{A}$ using the index set $I$ are confusing. First $I$ looks to be a fixed set, and then later it is allowed to range over all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. It looks to me like this extra set $I$ is completely unnecessary. $\mathscr{A}$ is $\{A_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$...full stop.
3. The line "Then $\mathscr{A}=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ and $I\subseteq I$" has two problems. First, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is $\mathbb{N}$, which is **not** the same as $\mathscr{A}$. Second, what is $I\subseteq I$ supposed to be adding to the sentence? This is a tautology. And, again, what is $I$? Is it fixed or not? (But again I suggest you just get rid of $I$ altogether.)
4. Your construction of $f$ and verification of its properties are the most cogent part of the proof. But there are still things to fix. The problem asks for a function with domain $\mathscr{A}$. But you construct a function with domain $\mathbb{N}$, and later talk about functions with domain some fixed $I$ (what is $I$???). So you just need to instead define $f$ so that $f(A_i)=i$ (this shows up later anyway). Finally, you use $A$ and $B$ for the domain and range of $f$, but without any clarification. If you are just renaming the domain and range of $f$, then don't--just continue to write $f:\mathscr{A}\to \mathbb{N}$. Otherwise, if $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be something else, then say what they are.

Comment: Thank you Mr. You soooo right...

I will try to fix it. I will write, if I ever need any assistance.

Thank you again. You helped me a lot.